# Install CD burner on Try Ubuntu

Tags: live-cd, cd, burning

Is it possible to install a CD-ROM burner when running Ubuntu from the installation media as "Try Ubuntu"

I have tried with apt instal brasero k3b etc. and none was possible to locate.

The reason for my request is that I want to generate some "secret" signing keys, and store a backup on a CD-ROM to store in a safe. And I need to do it next week.

Comment: If try works why not install it? Add the software and make the keys and delete what ever it is you think you need to delete.

Comment: The idea is that the procedure should be monitored by several developers, to ensure that the secret keys do not get cloned. Thus I'm not really interested in installing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running Ubuntu Desktop live 'Try Ubuntu', the repository `universe` must be added

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

and then you can install the burners

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install brasero k3b
```

---

You may want a persistent live system (optional), that you can make with [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb).